# How to pop back to a TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, tableview

I start of with a `tableViewController` that has a list of names. When the user taps on a name, they are segued to a view controller.

While in that `viewController` the user may press a button that will take them to another table view Controller.

The layout is like this:

```
TableViewController(1) -> ViewController -> TableViewController(2)
```

My question is, how can I pop back to the first `TableViewController` from the Second `TableViewController`.

My `rootViewController` is my `signIn` View controller so I cannot pop back to root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this to pop to your `rootViewController`:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

**Update:**
Since your `rootViewController` is not where you want to end up then you can iterate through your `controllers` and pop to a specific one:

```
for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers {
    if controller.isKind(of: TableViewControllerOne.self) { 
        self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
        break
    }
}
```

Instead of `TableViewControllerOne.self` update to your desired `controller`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that my root view controller is a ViewController where the user signs in.

Comment: But won't the views stack on top of each other? Is there a way to pop back to a tableViewController?

Comment: @JoseMelendez, check the update. Next time try to be as specific as possible in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with segues, you can implement an unwind segue.  That would give you the added benefit of passing information back to TableViewController(1) if you needed to.  To make that work in TableViewController1 you would add some code that looked like:

```
@IBAction func unwind(fromTableVC2 segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if (segue.source is TableVC2) {
        if let svc = segue.source as? TableVC2 {
             // pass information back
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your storyboard you would go to where you have your TableVC2 and drag the yellow VC circle to the exit and choose the function we created above.  Name the segue (for this example we'll call it "UnwindToTableVC1"), and then somewhere in TableVC2 add the code:

```
func setVariableToPassBack () {
    // Set up variables you want to pass back
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "UnwindToTableVC1", sender: self)    }
```

And that will take you back to your chosen destination with any information you wanted to pass back.

If you don't want to pass anything back, you really just need call the below line in your TableVC2:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "UnwindToTableVC1", sender: self)
```